# Convert multilevel hash in simple hash in perl

Tags: perl, hash

I have a hash that is multilevel hash i want to convert that into single level .But i am not able to do that

**Actual Hash:**

```
'MainSlab' => {
                'A1' => {
                           'Slab' => {
                                     '49_168' => {
                                                   'Amt' => '3000',
                                                   'Start' => '49',
                                                   'End' => '168'
                                                 },
                                     '169_720' => {
                                                    'Amt' => '3000',
                                                    'Start' => '169',
                                                    'End' => '720'
                                                  },
                                     '2_48' => {
                                                 'Amt' => '3000',
                                                 'Start' => '2',
                                                 'End' => '48'
                                               },
                                     '721_-' => {
                                                  'Amt' => '3000',
                                                  'Start' => '721',
                                                  'End' => '-'
                                                }
                                }
                         },
                     'A2' => {
                       'Slab' => {
                                 '49_168' => {
                                               'Amt' => '3000',
                                               'Start' => '49',
                                               'End' => '168'
                                             },
                                 '169_720' => {
                                                'Amt' => '4000',
                                                'Start' => '169',
                                                'End' => '720'
                                              },
                                 '2_48' => {
                                             'Amt' => '5000',
                                             'Start' => '2',
                                             'End' => '48'
                                           },
                                 '721_-' => {
                                              'Amt' => '3000',
                                              'Start' => '721',
                                              'End' => '-'
                                            }
                            }
                     }
              }
```

I want to convert that into simple and single level hash like this :

```
slab =>{
                "49_168"=>{"A1"=> "3000","A2"=>"3000"},
                "169_720"=>{"A1"=>"4000","A2"=>"4000"},
                "2_48"=>{"A1"=>"5000","A2"=>"5000"},
                "721_"=>{"A1"=>"3000","A2"=>"3000"}
        }
```

Please help me to do this how can we do this

Comment: You can move through hash and keep checking reference values. When reference of any key for hash or no hash. When it is not hash then use it and its key to create your single level hash.

Comment: It's not a single level at all, just restructuring it, but I've answered nonetheless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming

```
my %hash = (
    'MainSlab' => {
                'A1' => {
                           'Slab' => { 
                                      '49_168' => {
                                               'Amt' => '3000',
                                               'Start' => '49',
                                               'End' => '168'
                                             },
                 'A2' => ...
);
```

Then:

```
my $hashref     = $hash{'MainSlab'};
my $new_hashref = {};
foreach my $ax (keys %$hashref) {
   foreach my $k (keys %{$hashref->{$ax}{'Slab'}}) {
     $new_hashref->{$k}{$ax} = $hashref->{$ax}{'Slab'}{$k}{'Amt'};
   }
}
my %new_hash    = (slab => $new_hashref);
```

Will produce:

```
$new_hash = ( 'slab' => {
                 '49_168' => {
                        'A1' => '3000',
                        'A2' => '3000'
                      },
                 '169_720' => {
                         'A1' => '3000',
                         'A2' => '4000'
                 ...
           );
```

Comment: i want to add a key also if Start or End is greater than 48 then i want to add description key that will convert into number of days like 48_168 will have desc key as from "3 to 7days"

Comment: please help me in this

Answer (score 0):

```
use Data::Dumper qw();

## actual hash $h1
my $h1 = { 'MainSlab' => { 'A1' => { 'Slab' => { '49_168' => { 'Amt' => '3000', 'Start' => '49', 'End' => '168' }, '169_720' => { 'Amt' => '3000', 'Start' => '169', 'End' => '720' }, '2_48' => { 'Amt' => '3000', 'Start' => '2', 'End' => '48' }, '721_-' => { 'Amt' => '3000', 'Start' => '721', 'End' => '-' } } }, 'A2' => { 'Slab' => { '49_168' => { 'Amt' => '3000', 'Start' => '49', 'End' => '168' }, '169_720' => { 'Amt' => '4000', 'Start' => '169', 'End' => '720' }, '2_48' => { 'Amt' => '5000', 'Start' => '2', 'End' => '48' }, '721_-' => { 'Amt' => '3000', 'Start' => '721', 'End' => '-' } } } } };

## transform to $h2
my @l2 = keys(%{$h1->{'MainSlab'}});
my @l1 = keys(%{$h1->{'MainSlab'}->{$l2[0]}->{'Slab'}});
my $h2 = {};
foreach my $l1 (@l1) {
    my $inner = {};
    foreach my $l2 (@l2) {
        $inner->{$l2} = $h1->{'MainSlab'}->{$l2}->{'Slab'}->{$l1}->{'Amt'};
    } ## end foreach
    $h2->{'slab'}->{$l1} = $inner;
} ## end foreach

## print result
print(Data::Dumper->Dump([$h2],['$h2']));
```

Output:

```
$h2 = {
        'slab' => {
                    '49_168' => {
                                  'A1' => '3000',
                                  'A2' => '3000'
                                },
                    '169_720' => {
                                   'A1' => '3000',
                                   'A2' => '4000'
                                 },
                    '2_48' => {
                                'A1' => '3000',
                                'A2' => '5000'
                              },
                    '721_-' => {
                                 'A1' => '3000',
                                 'A2' => '3000'
                               }
                  }
      };
```

Comment: The dereference arrow `->` is not necessary after the first.